# Multi object type nested LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I'm populating my xaml binding an `ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>` called *DaysCollection* to an `ItemsControl`'s `ItemSource`.

The objects I'm pushing in the list are of type `Day`
Each object has a similar structure: an `ItemsControl` which `ItemSource` is populated with `Things` objects, which have a TimeStamp property.

I'm trying to find inside the *DaysCollection* list using LINQ the `Things` object containing the correct TimeStamp.

I tried the following:

```
var test = DaysCollection .Where(x => (x.DataContext as List<Days>).Any(y => (y.DataContext as List<Things>).Any(z => z.TimeStamp == value))).First();
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'
```

Comment: `Where(x => (x.DataContext as List<Days>)` should be `Where(x => (x.DataContext is List<Days>)`, then your as comand should work and you find the timestamp

Comment: If I use `is` instead of `as` I get: *bool does not contain a definition for Any and no accessible extension method [...]*

Answer (score -1):

As the `as` cast operation can return null when the types do not much, the subsequent call to `.Any()` might result in the exception you described above.

Are you absolutely certain that DataContext internally is of Type `List<Days>`? If not, try using `IEnumerable<Days>` instead, which allows a much broader selection of collection implementations.

Furthermore you should check the cast for null using the null conditional (`?.`) and null coalescing (`??`) operators. The code below might work, but it's possible you might need some more brackets. ;)

Also `.First()` ensures that you receive at least one and exactly one element. (Though there might be more in the collection.) If your query does not return a result, this will also throw an exception. You might want to use `.FirstOrDefault()` if you want to handle that case on your own.

```cs
var test = DaysCollection
  .Where(x => (x.DataContext as IEnumerable<Days>)
    ?.Any(y => (y.DataContext as IEnumerable<Things>)
      ?.Any(z => z.TimeStamp == value) ?? false)
    ?? false
  ).First();
```

Comment: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

CS1662: Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: I never said the code works copy-paste ;) The null conditional operator returns a nullable bool (`bool?`) which you have to "turn" into a non-nullable `bool`. That's what the `?? false` is for. I edited my answer and added another `?? false`, which now works in a dotnetfiddle I setup:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ScLQV5

If you encounter further issues, please describe what you did in order to solve them. I'd love to know how you handle these problems before copy-pasting the error into SO. ;) I don't want to offend you, I just aim for you to be able to solve the problem on your own.